# How to get Tweet preview image

Tags: javascript, twitter, meta-tags, tweets

I'm trying to get a Tweet's meta tags from its link. I can get the meta tags using a module called `html-metadata-parser`. My problem is when I look at Twitter's meta tags I don't see a tag for image on the tweet. But when I post the link in chats such as Discord, Instagram and Whatsapp it shows me the image of the Tweet too. Anyone know how can I get the link to the preview image?

```js
 require('dotenv').config();

    const router = require('express').Router();
    const Meta = require('html-metadata-parser');
    const axios = require('axios');
    const Jimp = require('jimp');

    router.post('/webhooks/discounts', async (res, req) => {
    const { link, provider, oauth } = req.body;

    if (
        oauth === process.env.IFTTTOAUTH
    ) {

        var response = await Meta.parser(link);
        const metaTags = JSON.stringify(response, null, 3);

        let hasImage;
        let ProviderNameURL;

        await metaTags.og.images[0] ? hasImage = true : hasImage = false;
        provider === "Steam" ? ProviderNameURL = "steam" : provider === "Ubisoft" ? ProviderNameURL = "ubisoft" : provider === "EpicGames" ? ProviderNameURL = "epic_games" : provider === "GOG.com" ? ProviderNameURL = "gog_com" : provider === "Humble Bundle" ? ProviderNameURL = "humble_bundle" : "unknown";

        const text = await metaTags.og.description;
        const image = hasImage === true ? await metaTags.og.images[0].url : null;
        const icon = `https://cdn.syfac.xyz/images/game_markets/${ProviderNameURL}.png`;
        const urlToDiscount = link;

        try {
            axios.post(requesterURL, {
                text,
                image,
                provider,
                icon,
                urlToDiscount,
                hasImage,
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    } else {return;}
    })

    module.exports = router;
```

This is my code. `og:image` is not what I'm looking for since it respresents the profile image.

When I was checking Twitter's meta tags I saw a link tag with preconnect and one with dns-prefetch and they both go to //pbs.twimg.com and when I checked the şmage source from the embed in Discord it was a link from pbs.twimg.com so I think I have some progress but I still don't know how to get the image.

Comment: Is it "og:image" that you're looking for? Also, it would be helpful if you provide your code and the some results

Comment: @mertdökümcü When I checked Twitter's meta tags I saw og:image but that was for the user's profile picture who created the tweet. I will edit my question and add my code too.

Comment: Just posted a possible solution. Hope it works. I think you need to use Twitter API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I get it right, what you are looking for is the preview image generated for a Tweet. You can use Twitter API for such an operation. Over time I found out that working with Twitter's API is much better compared to parse/scrape it.  Please see: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/media

What you need to do is:

- Get a Twitter Developer account. This will help you access the Twitter API.
- Use the API and get detailed information about Tweets and/or Twitter users.

Here is an example:

Sample Tweet URL: https://twitter.com/TravelVida/status/1380913486931361794
so the ID is: `1380913486931361794`.

I used this ID to create a request and used it with Postman. In your case, you should adapt this call to your JavaScript code. Here is the request URL:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/:id?expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=duration_ms,height,media_key,preview_image_url,public_metrics,type,url,width
```

And the response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "3_1380913484095963145",
                "3_1380913484456718339"
            ]
        },
        "id": "1380913486931361794",
        "text": "Amankila, Bali, Indonesia \nvia: bennyjurdi 
    },
    "includes": {
        "media": [
            {
                "height": 1537,
                "width": 1242,
                "media_key": "3_1380913484095963145",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Eyn9f1UWQAkLAFe.jpg",
                "type": "photo"
            },
            {
                "height": 1540,
                "width": 1242,
                "media_key": "3_1380913484456718339",
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Eyn9f2qW8AMbC0-.jpg",
                "type": "photo"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The last image's preview URL is what you need.
Image URL: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Eyn9f2qW8AMbC0-.jpg

Preview: [image]

Comment: That's super cool but I wasn't accepted for a twitter dev account...

Comment: There is no other way I guess

Comment: I created a new account and will see if it gets accepted, I hope it does

Answer (score 0):

this header can get the right image from almost url

```
headers: {
"user-agent": "googlebot", // fetches with googlebot crawler user agent
"Accept-Language": "fr-CA", // fetches site for French language
}
```